# how to I create new product using catalogProductCreate method in Magento

Tags: magento

How do I create a new product using the `catalogProductCreate` method in Magento? How to pass the parameters which are used in this method when I call this method from wsdl class?

Answer (score 0):

Below example code from this [Documentation link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html)

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// get attribute set
$attributeSets = $client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($session);
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);

$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple', $attributeSet->set_id, 'product_sku', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
));
```

Comment: thnks for reply. But how to pass this parameter in salesforce not a php.